# Performance: COALESCE resultset against NULL vs. @@ROWCOUNT

Tags: sql, performance, select, stored-procedures, null

I'm currently writing a stored procedure that provides a calling application with the retrieval of valid city and state values.
When provided with a zip_code, the stored procedure will return a list of all valid city/state combinations for the specified input parameter.
However, if a zip_code does not exist, then the stored procedure must return an error string 'ZipCode Wrong!' back to the calling application instead of an empty dataset.
I've considered two approaches:

### First Approach

```
SELECT City, State FROM ZipCodeTable WHERE Zip = @ZipCode
IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
return 'ZipCode Wrong!'
```

### Second Approach

```
SELECT COALESCE(  
               (SELECT City, State FROM ZipCodeTable WHERE Zip=@ZipCode FOR XML PATH ('')),
               (SELECT 'ZipCode Wrong!') FOR XML PATH (''))
```

As this transaction will be run MANY, MANY times per second, I want to make it as efficient as possible.  From a performance standpoint which one is more efficient?  Also, if there's another, better approach, feel free to let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tested your second approach?  I don't think it's valid syntax.

Comment: How can COALESCE use a multiple-column select as a parameter? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/163

Comment: why don't you want to handle this on application side? Id result is null or dataset is empty return `'ZipCode Wrong!'`

Comment: How are you returning the city and state?  The way you've posed the problem, you have one query returning two results and another returning one result.  Can't combine them like that.

Comment: @NWest Good catch, I forgot the second SELECT.

Comment: @TelJanini That won't work either. It's got a multiple-column select and a single column select. COALESCE requires a scalar parameter...

Comment: Why exactly are you not handling this in the application?

Comment: @biziclop You're right, I neglected to add the FOR XML PATH to the question.  Thanks!

Comment: @rs., msmucker0527 Unfortunately it's a legacy app (actually a collection of legacy apps), and I have no access to the code; I can only change the sproc on the SQL Server side.

Comment: Hmmm, this appears to be SQL Server.  Stored procedures return integers.  I'm not aware that they return strings.

Comment: What does the legacy application take back as a the return result from the proc?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff You're right, by return I mean it picks up the result of the SELECT using a DataReader.

Comment: @NWest It takes back an XML string using a DataReader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should handle this in the application layer. Look at the number of rows returned and detect the error that way. Much faster, easier and cleaner than a SQL solution.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you don't use a `COUNT` and don't use a `SELECT` because one *counts* your results and the other returns a set.

You *really* mean to ask whether or not it exists... so why not use the clause intended for that purpose?

`EXISTS`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx

If you, instead, want to return the result if it exists, and the error message if it doesn't, then `@@ROWCOUNT` is likely faster... you should benchmark it using the profiler.

Consider your use case, though.
Do you expect significantly more errors and valid returns? If so, then perhaps the `EXISTS` syntax is better as a filter... if you expect much more valid returns then the `SELECT` with `@@ROWCOUNT` may be preferred.

For this one, the answer is pretty squarely: **It depends**

What database are you using? Perhaps there is an implementation-specific approach for this.

Comment: The database is SQL Server 2008 R2.  Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

IF Then branches generally take more time, COALESCE is easier for your processor to optimize.

That said, they will probably run at equal speed, I would speed test both solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create an entire result when you don't need it, just make a count:

```
declare @cnt int
select @cnt = count(*) from ZipCodeTable where Zip = @ZipCode
if (@cnt) begin
  return 'ZipCode Wrong!'
end
```

Comment: Doesn't a count typically require a full scan of the table each time... It may be even faster just to do a `select top 1 zip where zip = @ZipCode` if all that's needed is a confirmation of the existence of the zip in the table.

Comment: Why bother counting the results?